# What is the second clause modifying?

Tags: grammar, modifiers

> I went to swimming pool three times a week through out my childhood, *Monday, Tuesday, and Friday morning practices that were exhausting but fruiful.*

I simply cannot find the clause  "a Monday...fruitul" is modifying. Is it modifying the going to the swimming pool, which would be "I went to the swimming pool," or is it modifying the "three times" part, or, even though I  think it's possible, is it modifying the whole clause that came before the italicized clause?

Please tell me what part of the first clause the second clause is modifying. 
Thank you.

Comment: It's not modifying anything, it's providing more details about the first clause: which three days of the week.

Comment: Can you tell me what the giving of more details used in this sentence is called?

Comment: A word for that is _elaborating_.

Comment: I don't know what the indefinite article 'a' is doing in that sentence. It doesn't match with 'practices'. Have you typed it correctly?

Comment: @Barmar Also, what do you mean by which three day of the week? Do you just simply mean these are details or do you mean that word "which" had to come before the second clause?

Comment: @chasly from UK edited it!

Comment: The first clause says he want to the pool 3 days a week. The second clause gets more specific, saying that those 3 days were Monday, Tuesday, and Friday. If I'd written that, I would have separated the two clauses with a colon `:`, since the second clause is a list of details.

Comment: So it's describing the three times a week. And is it generally recommended for writers to use colon when the second clause is list of details, or do you just prefer it?

Comment: I'd say the part of the sentence beginning at "Monday" is in apposition to "three days a week".

Answer (score 0):

As I read this, keeping in mind that I am a first year student, I read "Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday" as that which is modifying. 
Without those, it reads, 
"I went to swimming pool three times a week through out my childhood, morning practices that were exhausting but fruiful."

I would think this would be the modifying factor.
Hoping to learn something here, as well. Thank you